# Essentially self-adjoint operator A

Tags: adjoint-operators, unbounded-operators

A is essentially self-adjoint if and only if the equation $A^ * x = -x$ has no non-trivial solutions. Where in addition, A is a densely defined, symmetric and positive operator.

I considered a solution to the equation $A^*x=-x$ and then I considered 
$0=<x, (A^*+I)x>$, my question is whether it is possible to do the next step $<(A+I)x, x>=<x, (A^*+I)x>$ and why I can do it.

Comment: Isn't it  by very definition of an adjoint operator ?

Comment: I only have the condition $A\subseteq A^*$

Comment: You probably can't do it, but $A$ is densely defined, so there's a sequence $x_n\to x$ for which you can apply it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please use the symbols \langle and \rangle for $\langle x,y\rangle$: it displays much better than using < and >.